# Display [object Promise] in String

Tags: javascript, object, url, promise, discord.js

i try to build a Discord bot with a Deeplink to klick in the embed.
But the bot only shows a [object Promise]. (the link contains a variable, so i can´t display it simple with url, i trie to shorten it with tinyurl when its ready and then display it.
so here is my code:

```
   const deeplink = TinyURL.shorten(`iota://${donation_address}/$amout=1&message=test`).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res)
        return res
      
     });
```

and here is the code for the embed:

```
addFields([
            {
                name: "Open with App",
                value: deeplink
            },
```

anyone an idea what im doing wrong? I want to show the shortened link.

thanks in advance

Comment: TL;DR: move the `addFields(...)` call into the `then(...)` callback.

Comment: Or use `await`, which would look cleaner in this situation imo